# First Come First set

Tags: c#, algorithm, cpu

I have a problem because I write a program in C # about the fcfs algorithm and I have a question how to import from a datagridview into an algorithm and then show on my datagridview2 here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Projekt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table.Columns.Add("Process", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Arrival Time", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Burst Time", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Piority", typeof(int));

            table.Rows.Add("1");
            table.Rows.Add("2");
            table.Rows.Add("3");
            table.Rows.Add("4");


            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Random rand = new Random();
            dataGridView1[1, 0].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[2, 0].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[3, 0].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[1, 1].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[2, 1].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[3, 1].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[1, 2].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[2, 2].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[3, 2].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[1, 3].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[2, 3].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
            dataGridView1[3, 3].Value = rand.Next(5, 30);
        }

        private void FCFS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

could you help me i this problem

Comment: You can create a class that represent the process. And then use a collection to bind the datasource of the grid.

Comment: Why is `algorithm` tagged lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  Columns 0 & 3 are int, while columns 1 & 2 arre strings.  You cannot put an int into a string column

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Projekt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table.Columns.Add("Process", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Arrival Time", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Burst Time", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Piority", typeof(int));

            table.Rows.Add("1");
            table.Rows.Add("2");
            table.Rows.Add("3");
            table.Rows.Add("4");


            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Random rand = new Random();
            table.Rows[0][0] = rand.Next(5, 30);
            table.Rows[1][0] = rand.Next(5, 30);
            table.Rows[2][0] = rand.Next(5, 30);
            table.Rows[3][0] = rand.Next(5, 30);
            table.Rows[0][3] = rand.Next(5, 30);
            table.Rows[1][3] = rand.Next(5, 30);
            table.Rows[2][3] = rand.Next(5, 30);
            table.Rows[3][3] = rand.Next(5, 30);

            dataGridView1 = null;  //to force update
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void FCFS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table2 = table.Clone();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = table2;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This two lines not working

dataGridView1 = null;  //to force update
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

They clone only columns not rows with values